# integrating prometheus with play + spring application

Tags: spring, playframework, prometheus, micrometer

I am new to prometheus + spring. My application runs on play + spring. In order to use micrometer for monitoring, I added :

`"org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-actuator" % "2.2.4.RELEASE"`,

`"io.micrometer" % "micrometer-registry-prometheus" % "1.2.0"`

and `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include="prometheus"` in application.conf.
while trying to use spring boot actuator in spring application.

When I bring up my service locally and try to hit:

> http://localhost:<service_port>/actuator/prometheus

it gives 404.

Can anyone give any lead on this?

Comment: Are you able to get other actuators to work? I'm not familiar with using the Play framework with Spring.

Comment: No /actuator api itself is giving 404

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus endpoint is provided by the Spring Actuators. Those are endpoints that are automatically created. I don't believe there is any support for the Play Framework and those actuators.

You could use [play prometheus filters](https://github.com/stijndehaes/play-prometheus-filters) to create the play equivalent endpoint. You'll want to ensure the `CollectorRegistry` is the same between the Play and Micrometer metrics.